# convert type variable to generic parameter

Tags: c#

Currently I have this method

```
    public void HandleComponent<T>() where T : IComponent
    {
        // do something with T
    }
```

and I would like to have a method `HandleComponents` where I can pass in multiple generic types and this method loops through them and calls `HandleComponent<currentGenericType>`.

**I know that it's not possible to have a variable number of generic parameters** but how can I create a workaround for this problem? I started creating this

```
    public void HandleComponents(Type[] components)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
        {
            HandleComponent<components[i]>(); // This is not possible
        }
    }
```

1. `components[i]` needs to get converted because currently this is not a generic parameter
2. I have to make sure, that each `Type` argument implements `IComponent`. I know I can check this within the method but I want to prevent passing in invalid arguments. So the method would have to look like (Pseudo Code)

   ```
   public void HandleComponents(Type[] components) where components : IComponent
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
       {
           HandleComponent<components[i]>();
       }
   }
   ```

   and this is not possible, right?

The perfect solution would look like this

```
public void HandleComponents<AListOfGenericTypes>() where EachGenericListItem : IComponent
{
    for (int i = 0; i < AListOfGenericTypes.Count; i++)
    {
        HandleComponent<AListOfGenericTypes[i]>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is not much possible, maybe you can use some kind of tuple-like implementation where you define a lot of overloads of same method generic types

Comment: The problem is, at the point in time that you're writing code that *consumes* generics, you have to know the specific types that you wish to substitute (be they concrete types or your own generic type parameters if you're also implementing something generic). There's no runtime option without going down the reflection route.

Comment: See also the families of types with names like `Func` and `Action`. There's just no way to be generic across an unknown number of type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IComponent cp1 = new Component1();//Created here or elsewhere
        IComponent cp2 = new Component2();//Created here or elsewhere
        IComponent cp3 = new Component3();//Created here or elsewhere

        HandleComponents<IComponent>(cp1, cp2, cp3);
    }

    private static void HandleComponents<T>(params T[] components) where T : IComponent
    {
        foreach (T component in components)
        {
            HandleComponent(component);
        }
    }

    private static void HandleComponent<T>(T component) where T : IComponent
    {
       //Do whatever with T
    }
}

public class Component1 : IComponent { }

public class Component2 : IComponent { }

public class Component3 : IComponent { }

public interface IComponent { }
```

Comment: You cannot have different concrete types that implement `IComponent` passed in a single call to that `HandleComponents`, method, which I think is what the OP is looking for. There's no type for `T` if they aren't all the same type.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you please explain ? The code above is compiling for me !

Comment: That's because you're forcing `T` to be `IComponent`, not any of the concrete types, which kind-of defeats the point here. If the OP wants that, they can have a non-generic `HandleComponents(params IComponent[] component)`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't want to instantiate new objects when passing in types. I tried to modify your code I hope this makes some things clear https://pastebin.com/fWBR0DiF is it possible to make this work?

Comment: @Question3r you don't have to. You can pass in objects that implement IComponent. If they don't (like InvalidComponent) the compiler will thrown an error.

Comment: So I fix the "is a variable but is used like a type" by passing in `T` instead of `component`. But how can I pass in the types without creating new objects? Sure I know how to use `typeof(Component1)` but the methods expects me to pass in an object

Comment: So it's not possible to simply pass in type arguments?

Comment: @Question3r not with this approach. I still don't get why you even need that sry ^^

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible without reflection. I advice you to rewrite method `HandleComponent`:

```
public void HandleComponent(Type objectType)
{
    // do something with T
}
```

And you can call:

```
public void HandleComponents(Type[] components)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
    {
        HandleComponent(components[i]);
    }
}
```

Reflection solution:

```
public void HandleComponents(Type[] components)
{
    var method = this.GetType().GetMethod("HandleComponent");
    for (int i = 0; i < components.Length; i++)
    {
        method.MakeGenericMethod(components[i])
            .Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but I need to make sure, that each Type implements the interface

Comment: @Question3r you can add runtime check `typeof(IComponent).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);`

Comment: yeah sorry but I want to prevent passing in invalid arguments. So yes it works but then I would have to do some checks instead of preventing it

Comment: So, you can't mix generic and non-generic methods without reflection.

Comment: Would you mind providing a reflection example if you think that this will be a working solution?

Comment: @Question3r added in answer

Comment: but I still would have to check if each type is a valid one right?

Comment: @Question3r reflection will check for you, if you pass wrong type, it will fail

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this and you're able to accept that you'll have a upper-bound on the actual number of components that can be passed, take inspiration from the `Func`, `Action` and `Tuple` families of types, and get your copy & paste fingers warmed up:

```
public void HandleComponent<T>(T component) where T : IComponent
{
    //Real logic
}

public void HandleComponents<T1, T2>(T1 component1, T2 component2)
    where T1 : IComponent
    where T2 : IComponent
{
    HandleComponent(component1);
    HandleComponent(component2);
}

public void HandleComponents<T1, T2, T3>(T1 component1, T2 component2, T3 component3)
    where T1 : IComponent
    where T2 : IComponent
    where T3 : IComponent
{
    HandleComponent(component1);
    HandleComponent(component2);
    HandleComponent(component3);
}
```

It's not ideal, and like I say, it imposes an upper bound on how many components can be passed to a single call. Because each call has to be separately parameterized, there's no way to use a loop here.

---

Or:

```
public void HandleComponent<T>() where T : IComponent
{
    //Real logic
}

public void HandleComponents<T1, T2>()
    where T1 : IComponent
    where T2 : IComponent
{
    HandleComponent<T1>();
    HandleComponent<T2>();
}
public void HandleComponents<T1, T2, T3>()
    where T1 : IComponent
    where T2 : IComponent
    where T3 : IComponent
{
    HandleComponent<T1>();
    HandleComponent<T2>();
    HandleComponent<T3>();
}
```

---

Here's the [text template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017) to cut down on copy & pasting (and to be more reusable for other methods):

Add `CreateHandleComponents.tt` as a text template to your project, and then give it this content:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

partial class Program {
  <# for(int i = 2; i < 16; i++)
    {
      Write("public void HandleComponents<");
      for(int j = 1; j<=i ;j++) {
      if (j>1) {
            Write(",");
        }
            Write("T{0}",j);
      }
        WriteLine(">()");
        for(int j = 1; j<= i; j++) {
          WriteLine("where T{0} : IComponent",j);
        }
        WriteLine("{");
        for(int j = 1; j<= i; j++) {
          WriteLine("HandleComponent<T{0}>();",j);
        }
        WriteLine("}");
  } #>
}
```

(You'll want to edit line 8 for whatever class these methods should be going into and make sure that it's marked as partial elsewhere. Also adjust for namespaces)

Comment: yes, this was my first solution and I think it's the only possible one but I have multiple methods that would require this copy paste chaos ... so I was hoping for something dynamic

Comment: The reason I reference `Func`, `Action` and `Tuple` here is that they're *core* types. If they didn't get a workaround or language enhancement for those, it's doubtful that mere mortals will do better. Of course, C&P is only one option. Have you ever worked with tools such as T4 templates or PostSharp?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever could you please explain how this is different to my approach ?

Comment: @Question3r - I've added a T4 template example at the end. It's a way of doing code generation within the project, which means I now have all overloads up to 16 types having only written 28 lines of code myself.

Comment: @FelixD. - mine always calls `HandleComponent` with the correct type parameter (not `IComponent`) and the type constraints are enforced at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to achieve what you want exactly, but you can overcome this by using reflection and [MakeGenericMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get your generic HandleComponent method and invoking it with the types passed in to the HandleComponents method, just the filtering of the passed in types has to happen in the for loop and not by generic constraint as there is no generic about that method.

```
class Program
{
    public interface IComponent { }
    public class ComponentA : IComponent { }
    public class ComponentB : IComponent { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HandleComponents(new[] { typeof(ComponentB), typeof(ComponentA) });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void HandleComponent<T>()
        where T : IComponent
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
    }

    private static void HandleComponents(Type[] components)
    {
        var m = typeof(Program).GetMethod("HandleComponent", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (var component in components)
        {
            if (typeof(IComponent).IsAssignableFrom(component))
            {
                var genericMethod = m.MakeGenericMethod(component);
                genericMethod.Invoke(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```